# css modules reference keyframe name inside jsx

Tags: reactjs, animation, webpack, css-loader, css-modules

I'm using css modules with `css-loader`, and I've stumbled upon a problem.
I have a `LoadingOverlay` component which shows a loader for duration ms.
I apply a fade-in-out animation on the overlay with the following code inside the component:

```
if (show) {
   return {
       animation: `fade-out-long ${duration}ms ease-out forwards`
   };
}
```

This style object is applied to the overlay node.
I do it this way since the duration is prop which is passed from the parent component.
My problem is that `LoadingOverlay.scss` is a scss module which uses `@include` to include animations like so:

```
@import '../../../constants/animations';

@include fade-out-long-keyframes();
@include fade-out-long2-keyframes();
```

and the animation name is getting compiled as-well to something like `LoadingOverlay-module__fade-out-long`.

How can I reference the correct animation name from my jsx then?

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss `:global` on keyframe. You must write keyframe with :global like below

```
@keyframes :global(slideInFromRight) {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes that would be an option but instead I've just used `animation-name` inside my scss module and used `animation-duration` inside my jsx, this way I can keep my `animations.scss` not a scss module file and also let the `css-loader` transform the keyframe name as it does while still being able to inject animation duration as a prop.